# Unable to import excel to database, array has no value

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5, maatwebsite-excel

I'm trying to import my excel to my database but the problem is that i get nothing in my array of inserts. When i try to dd($inserts), it only shows me 
"[]".

```
public function importExcel()
{
    $path = Input::file('import_file')->getRealPath();
    $inserts = [];
    Excel::load($path, function($reader) use ($inserts) {
        foreach ($reader->toArray() as $rows) { // <-- $rows pertains to array of rows
            foreach($rows as $row) { // <-- $row pertains to the row itself
                $inserts[] = ['title' => $row['title'], 'description' => $row['description']];
            }
        }    
    });
    dd($inserts);
    return back();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've already have an answer for this in your previous question, you're modifying `$inserts` array but it's just a local variable inside that closure, you need to provide a reference to it if you want to modify it, just update your closure signature to this.

```
function($reader) use (&$inserts)
//                     ^-- add this to use its reference.
```

Thus when you modify it inside the closure, it will now reflect outside the closure.

Comment: Oh yeah i posted it awhile ago before you answered the previous question @Wreigh

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do same things:

> Define private variables before constructor if you defined.

```
Class Test { //class name;
    private $inserts;//define after class name

    public function importExcel()
    {
    $path = Input::file('import_file')->getRealPath();
    Excel::load($path, function($reader) {
    foreach ($reader->toArray() as $rows) { 
       foreach($rows as $row) { 
            $this->inserts[] = ['title' => $row['title'], 'description' => $row['description']];
        }
    }    
    });
dd($this->inserts);
```

}